# new Option() vs <option>

Tags: javascript, dom

Is there any difference between adding an `option` to a `select` via:

```
mySelect.options[mySelect.options.length] = new Option('val', 'key');
```

vs

```
$('#mySelect').append('<option value="key">val</option>');
```

Does one perform better? Do only certain browsers support `new Option()`? etc

Comment: In some versions of IE it might not be supported. Anyway, the difference is in the language... the one is direct HTML which is just hidden into a JavaScript, and appears in certain conditions, the another is JS Object interprating on language level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new Option()` is faster but may not be cross-browser (version) compatible.  The jQuery solution is better because one of the selling points of jQuery is to ensure cross-browser compatibility.  Also, whatever gain there is in efficiency is too insubstantial to care about.

Answer (score 1):

`new Option()` is faster because it doesn't use external libraries (jQuery in your case)